# simple_form custom input for a composed_of aggregate attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, simple-form

I'm trying to write a custom input for the simple_form gem for a Rails 3 model which has a composed_of aggregate attribute. See the example below.

I tried using fields_for but it generates params like `"person"=>{"name"=>{"fname"=>"James","middle"=>"T","lname"=>"Kirk"}` which does not get handled by `Person.create` nor update_attributes like an association would.

Gives the following error

```
undefined method `fname' for {"fname"=>"James", "middle"=>"T", "lname"=>"Kirk"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

How would you implement this?

Example

```
$ rails g scaffold person last_name:string first_name:string middle_name:string
```

lib/fullname.rb

```
class Fullname
  attr_reader :fname, :middle, :lname

  def initialize(fname, middle, lname)
    @fname, @middle, @lname = fname, middle, lname
  end
end
```

app/models/person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  composed_of :name, 
              :class_name => 'Fullname', 
              :mapping => 
              [ # database      # Fullname
                [:first_name,   :fname], 
                [:middle_name,  :middle], 
                [:last_name,    :lname]
              ],
              :allow_nil => true
end
```

app/views/people/_form.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for @person do |f|
  = f.input :name, :as => :fullname
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

app/inputs/fullname_input.rb

```
class FullnameInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    @builder.simple_fields_for attribute_name, :validate => false do |form|
      [   'First:', form.input_field(:fname, :size => 10),
          'Middle:', form.input_field(:middle, :size => 5),
          'Last:', form.input_field(:lname, :size => 10)
      ].join(' ').html_safe
    end
  end
end
```